# Change Detection using Raster Calculator

Tags: raster-calculator, change-detection

I'm currently analyzing the change detection for urban expansion over a decade starting from 2006-2016.

How can I use raster calculator in order to know the changes?

For example, from agriculture to urban area and etc. I already classified the images into 4 classes, urban area,vegetation,water bodies and barren land.

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: What's your goal? To identify where there were changes, or to be able to discern from a single output what the particular changes were?

Answer (score 6):

Try reclassifying the rasters to a different scale of numbers, such as

```
urban = 1
ag = 10
forest = 100
water = 1000
```

Then just subtract the rasters in Raster Calculator:

```
0 will mean unchanged.
9 will mean ag --> urban
-9 will mean urban --> ag
99 will mean forest --> urban
90 will mean forest --> ag
-99 will mean urban --> forest etc.
```