# Land cover change detection using raster calculator in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, time-series, land-cover, change-detection

I am trying to find the difference between land cover data from two years. I have used the same classification for both the raster files. For eg:

1-Agriculture
2-Forest
3-Urban
4-Water bodies
5-Barren lands
6-Bare areas

If I want to calculate the change using the raster calculator in QGIS, do I need to reclassify either of the rasters to different values? And what should be the order of rasters in raster-calculator? Will the interpretation of results stay the same with different orders? For eg: If I have data from years 2019 and 2020, then should it be 2020-2019 or 2019-2020?

Also, help me understand how to interpret the results. I found a similar question on this forum, [Change Detection using Raster Calculator](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219608/change-detection-using-raster-calculator), but it is still not very clear to me.

Comment: Are you simply interested in knowing where change occured, or are the old and new categories of interest to you? Case one is a simple "raster2-raster1"

Comment: @Erik, I don't know what you exactly meant by case 2. I reclassified 2020 raster to different values (eg: 100, 200, 300...) and then subtracted raster 1 from raster 2(reclassified). I don't know how to interpret the results. For eg: I get values such as -140, 580, 220 etc. Can you help me interpret this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what J. Kelly responded on [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219608/change-detection-using-raster-calculator) also applies here. The idea behind it is to reclassify to numbers which generate unique values when subtracted. This way, instead of "Forest --> Agriculture" resulting -1 and "Forest --> Urban" also resulting -1, the first operation will result 9 and second operation will result 90, which will make it easier to differentiate between them. So, in both rasters, I would use Reclassify by table:

[image: Table to reclassify]

About performing the calculation of Raster2020-Raster2019 or the opposite on the Raster Calculator, it does not matter, it just has to interpreted accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation@L. Lucchese.